# Set header and footer to content height, and content section consumes all free space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my page, I don't know the height of both header and footer. let the header and footer take it height according to the content.

reset of the height from the 100% i am giving to content section. I am trying but not getting the result. any one help me?

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

div.wrapp{
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

header{
  flex:1;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

section{
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
}

footer{
  flex:1;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <header>asfsdf</header>
  <section>sfasfsdf</section>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want that the `section` takes the remaining *height*:

```css
/* unnecessary is commented out */
* {box-sizing: border-box}

html, body {
  height: 100%; /* can also use viewport units (100vh) */
  margin: 0;
}

div.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; /* same here */
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

header {
  /*flex:1;*/
  /*width:100%;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section {
  flex: 1; /* does the trick */
  /*height:100%;*/
}

footer {
  /*flex:1;*/
  /*width:100%;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <header>header</header>
  <section>section</section>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```